# Sometimes AMOLED display turns green or purple (tinted)

Tags: samsung, screen, super-amoled

I am using Samsung Galaxy A5 A500G since last month, but sometimes while using the phone, the display turns slightly green or purple (tinted) in shade. But as soon as I adjust the screen brightness, the display becomes normal.

Is it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a problem ?

Not if it vanishes by increasing brightness a bit or moving out of shade. It is a problem if you see this with normal day time brightness

**Why does it happen?**

Samsung AMOLED displays are based on [PenTile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PenTile_matrix_family) technology and manufactured by [Nouvoyance](http://www.nouvoyance.com/technology-what.html) ( Nouvouyance partners with Samsung and  also supplies Pentile displays to other OEMs as well). Instead of the conventional (called Real Stripe) OLED displays pixel pattern of `RGB` , PenTile uses `RGBW`, which cuts power consumption to half for the same brightness and hence longer screen life as well

- This technology has   [disadvantage](http://www.tested.com/tech/2446-how-pentile-displays-are-brighter-but-not-always-better/) of  colours looking grainy, *more so warmer colours. This effect is visually more pronounced in low brightness*

(OR)

- Red LEDs consume least power for same brightness followed by Green and Blue, so when the screen is in low brightness *red is comparatively brighter and gives a pinkish/ greenish hue*. This is considered to be a [feature of Nexus 6 and not a bug](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/11/nexus-6-review-the-premium-price-still-comes-with-compromises/)

Any /combination of these two factors makes the color combination look tinted and variously described as purple, brown or pink. This should be the main reason for your observation (other being a problem with screen or screen digitizer, if it is very pronounced).